# RxJava - single Observable executing right away - why?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, subject-observer

I have a very simple RXJava emitter. It is a publishSubject actually but its job to convert Integers to strings and update a UI element afterwards when it subscribes.  The code looks like this :

```
PublishSubject integerToStringEmitter = PublishSubject.create();

    Subscription mysingle= Single.just(4).map(new Func1<Integer, String>() {


        @Override
        public String call(Integer integer) {
            return String.valueOf(integer);
        }
    }).subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            tv.setText(s);
        }
    });
// integerToStringEmitter.subscribe(); //it still emits even without this, why ?
```

What i want to happen: for subscription to only begin when i call **integerToStringEmitter.subscribe();**

What is happening currently :  As soon as i launch the program the onNext is getting called and the UI element is being set to the # 4. why ? i need more control over this thing so it does not execute right away without me even subscribing to it. Please help solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Your code doesn't look right and shouldn't even compile. If it would compile then the subscribe(new Observer() {... part would obviously trigger the event stream.

Here's a simple example of an Observable emitting integers and mapping them to Strings and an Observer subscribing to it:

```
Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4).map(new Func1<Integer, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Integer integer) {
        return String.valueOf(integer);
    }
});

Subscriber<String> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("onCompleted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("onError: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        System.out.println("onNext: " +s);
    }
};

myObservable.subscribe(mySubscriber);
```

Comment: It compiles fine. I was missing to not chain the subscriber. Thanks good advice.